# Well, your mother has got three windows into my dancing room~

Tags: sentence-meaning

> “Well, your mother has got three windows into my dancing room, and you have three into my garret.”

What does the above sentence mean?

Comment: Context, please!!!

Comment: One of entry sentences from a dictionary.

Comment: Please always give the source of sentences you ask about! This is a rather strange one; presumably it means that the mother can see into the 'dancing room' through three windows, and the person addressed can see into the speaker's attic room through three windows.

Comment: You really need to provide more text and context. We waste so much time repeating this to OPs, over and over.

Comment: I rather feel we should have a blanket ban on "what does the example sentence from a dictionary mean".  The purpose of example sentences is to show a word in context.  If you already understand the word,then you don't need the example sentence.  If you don't understand the word, then your question should be about the word, not the example.  "It's from a dictionary" is not a source.

Comment: @JamesK I take your comment into account. But sometimes there are cases where I know all the words and structure of the sentence and still don't get the real meaning.

Comment: Then it is a poor example.  Do you understand the meaning of the word that is being defined in the dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from [At the Back of the North Wind](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/269713.At_the_Back_of_the_North_Wind), by George MacDonald. The speaker is the North Wind herself, talking to the boy Diamond - she is claiming that her "house" is the whole of the outdoors, so that when people make windows in their houses to look outside, they are also making windows that look into her house. The three windows Diamond's mother have downstairs look into the equivalent of her dancing room, and the three windows Diamond has in his attic bedroom look into the equivalent of her garret.

(By "the equivalent of her garret" I mean that Diamond's higher up windows are looking into the higher up part of the outside, which, if we view "the outside" as her house, would be where the garret would be situated.)

Comment: What does 'the equivalent' of her garret'? I mean 'the equivalent'. (I know the definition in a dictionary but can't get the meaning of it here.)

Comment: talking, not taking. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the context one must assume a literal meaning.

The mother can see into the person's dancing room (the room that they use for dancing) through any of three windows. These windows are "hers" in the sense that she has access to them

And in addition, the person being spoken to can see into the speaker's garret (the small living space in the attic) through any of two windows.

Context might show that these rooms and windows are actually meant to be interpreted figuratively.  But you'll have to make that interpretation.